# Reverse number with sign

Tags: javascript, function, reverse

How can I reverse numbers including a sign? (eg: `-659 => -956`)

Also, numbers with zeros at the end should be reversed in the following way:

```
1000 => 1

50000 => 5
```

My current result is:

```
-784 => 487-

1000 => 0001
```

Here is my function:

```
function reverseNumber(num)
{
    num = num.toString();
    return num.split("").reverse().join("");
}
console.log(reverseNumber(-5698));
```

Comment: ok so can you point out where all your function fails ? then maybe we can tackle specific problems ?

Comment: So why do you need this?  It's an interesting requirement. :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can check for the sign of the number before processing. Here is a working example

```js
function reverseNumber(num)
{
  sign = num < 0 ? '-' : '';
  num = Math.abs(num) + "";
  return Number(sign + num.split("").reverse().join(""));
}
console.log(reverseNumber(-1000));
```

Comment: thank you, it works, but the problem:
1000 => 0001 is still occurring
should be like 1000 => 1

Comment: Before returning the result that was a string, I casted it into a number. As 0 in front of the number are filtered out, it gives the expected result

Answer (score 2):

You could save the sign and apply later by using the absolute value.

```js
function reverse(n) {
    return (n > 0 || -1) * Math.abs(n).toString().split('').reverse().join('');
}

console.log(reverse(-1000));
console.log(reverse(1000));
```

Comment: thank you, it works, but the problem:
1000 => 0001 is still occurring
should be like 1000 => 1

Comment: @John, it does it, because of the multiplication, all strings are converted to number.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an approach using a helper function to handle the reversal, then calling it conditionally in the `reverseNumber` function depending on the sign of `n`:

```js
const reverse = s => ("" + s).split("").reverse().join("");

const reverseNumber = n => +(n < 0 ? `-${reverse(-n)}` : reverse(n));

console.log(reverseNumber(-5698));
console.log(reverseNumber(-1));
console.log(reverseNumber(-1.3));
console.log(reverseNumber(1000));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way also with [Math.sign()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/sign) to check whether the number is positive, negative or zero. Then use a flag e.g `negative` to `false` initially if `Math.sign(num)` returns negative value i.e `<1` then set it to `true`. Also use [Math.abs()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/abs) to make it positive always before reversing it with `reverse()`. Finally put sign before number based on the `negative` flag.

```js
function reverseNumber(num) {
  pos_neg = Math.sign(num);
  negative = false;
  if (pos_neg < 1) {
    // treat as negative value
    negative = true;
    num = Math.abs(num);
  }

  num = num + "";
  expression = Number(num.split("").reverse().join(""));
  return negative ? - expression : expression ;
}
console.log(reverseNumber(1000));
console.log(reverseNumber(50000));
console.log(reverseNumber(-784))
```

Answer (score 0):

Set a `negative` flag f number is negative, **work with the absolute value** of the number, and convert it back to negative before returning, if the `negative` flag was set to true

```js
function reverseNumber(num){
    let negative = (num<0) ? true : false;
    num = Math.abs(num).toString();
    num = Number(num.split("").reverse().join("") )
    return negative ? (num*-1) : num 
}
console.log(reverseNumber(-5698));
console.log(reverseNumber(1000));
```

Answer (score 0):

First converting the number to its absolute value and then reversing it. If the number was negative appending the "-" sign at the end. Also if the reversed number has leading zeros then eliminating it with the help of reg expression.

```js
function reverseNumber(num)
{
   var reversed = Math.abs(num).toString().split("").reverse().join("");
   reversed = (num < 0) ? reversed + "-": reversed;
   return reversed.replace(/^0+/, '');
}
console.log(reverseNumber(10000));
console.log(reverseNumber(-987));
console.log(reverseNumber(-10000));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function reverseNumber(num)
{
    var sign = Math.sign(num);
    return parseInt(num.toString().replace("-","").split("").reverse().join(""),10) * sign;
}
```

More correct to handle floating point:

```
function reverseNumber(num)
{
    var sign = Math.sign(num);
    return Number(Math.Abs(num).toString().split("").reverse().join("")) * sign;
}
```

Comment: why did you add "10" at the end of this string?
`parseInt(num.toString().replace("-","").split("").reverse().join(""),10)`

Comment: It tells it to use base 10.  If it begins with a zero it won't parse correctly.  Using Number() is a better option.  It will also work with floating point numbers.